# mongoose convert string to ObjectId by _MONGOSH in mongo compass

Tags: mongodb, mongo-shell

I want to do simple database update using _MONGOSH in Mongo Compass. I am putting this query, and getting error: *Argument passed in must be a string of 12 bytes or a string of 24 hex characters or an integer;*

My query:

```
db.getCollection("col")
  .updateMany(
    {
      field: { $ne: null }
    },
    {
      field: ObjectId('$field')
    }
  )
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is how I solved this:

```
db.getCollection("col").find(
  {
    'field': { $type : 2 },
    'field': { $ne: null }
  })
    .forEach(async function(d){
        const id = ObjectId(d.field);
        d.field = id; 
        await db.getCollection("col").updateOne(
          { 
            _id: d._id
          },
          {
            $set: {
              'field': id
            }
          }
        )
        }
    )
```